Raspberry Pi Camera Inconsistent Color
I need photos of the face of a Rubik’s cube, and the colors in the photos turn out differently depending on how many colors are in frame. When there are more lots of vibrant colors, red orange green blue, in the photo, it turns out normal. However, when it is mostly colors like yellow, the photo comes out with terrible coloring. The color in the photos is just inconsistent.
Link to photo:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QIXgFpZW-wbq5E7ttPBLaLkSjWvz7K1D/view?usp=sharing

It would be better to upload the image into the question, rather than require users to have to click a link.
